# $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) \not = 0$ $\implies$ $\int_0^{\infty} f(x)dx$ diverges?

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

What can I use to prove the following:

If $f:[0, \infty[ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ integrable in all $[0,c]$, $c>0$
and

if (limit exists and) $$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) \not = 0$$ then  $$\int_0^{\infty} f(x)dx$$ diverges.

I understand the idea that the integral must diverge, since the terms of the sequence never go to zero (i.e. the integral or the sum continues accumulating to infinity).

However I'm lost as to what kind of notation to use to display this. I think I don't need Riemann sums in this.

Comment: if you do not add other conditions on $f$, it is not true. For a counter example, think about $f$ like this _/\_ making some triangles each one being smaller than the other and such that the sum of all these areas is finite.

Comment: When you say that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) \not = 0$, do you also suppose that the limit exists?

Comment: It is not necessarily true if $f$ is not continuous.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the following steps:

1. Let $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)=a\neq0$ and then, for a given (small) $\epsilon>0$ there exists $M>0$ such that $f(x)>a-\epsilon$ whenever $x>M$.
2. Separate the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x) dx = \int_{0}^{M}f(x) dx + \int_{M}^{\infty}f(x) dx$.
3. Use 1. to conclude that the second portion diverges and therefore, the integral diverges.

Comment: Yeah and I wonder that to use to display $\int_M^{\infty} f(x)dx$ diverges. Unless I need to use Riemann sum notation.

Comment: Why does the limit in 1 exists? The interesting case is when the limit doesn't exist...

Comment: @mavavilj I don't think you need to go back to Riemann sums.  Use "ML" estimate.  ie., you know $f(x)>a-\epsilon$ for $x>M$, so $\int_M^{\infty}f(x)dx = \lim_{L\to\infty}\int_M^Lf(x)dx > \lim_{L\to\infty}(L-M)\cdot(a-\epsilon) = \infty$