# $\int_0^{\infty} f(x)dx$ converges and $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x)$ exists, then $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x)=0$?

Tags: convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

Is the following true or false:

If $\int_0^{\infty} f(x)dx$ converges and $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x)$ exists, then $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x)=0$?

---

This should be doable without series.

Comment: This is false. In fact, $f$ can be the function which is zero everywhere except for the integer values of the argument, where $f(n)=1$. The integral exists and is zero, the limit does not exist.

Comment: Suppose it's not $0$ (say, $2$). Then for sufficiently large $x_1,x_2$, $\int_{[x_1,x_2]}f(x)dx \ge |x_2-x_1|$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I missed the hypothesis! Then the answer is definitely 'yes'! In fact, if the limit is $l\neq 0$ there exists $x_0$ such that $f(x)\in[l/2,3l/2]$ for any $x>x_0$ and the integral is $+\infty$ or $-\infty$

Comment: @guestDiego So does proving divergence for $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x)=l \not = 0$ prove that for $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) = 0$ there must be convergence? I don't feel it's very clear though.

Comment: No, you said by hypothesis that the integral is convergent, then you conclude that the limit (assumed existing) is zero. I am NOT sayng that since the limit is zero then there is convergence, which is false. Just the viceversa.

Comment: So how about assume the integral diverges and then prove that if the limit is $\not = 0$. Does this prove that if we "flip" the assumption from diverges to converges, then the limit is zero?

Comment: Why the self-duplicate? http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1780788

Answer (score 1):

Assume that
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=c>0$$
Then there exists $R$ such that $f(x)>c/2$ for all $x>R$.

Let
$$\int_0^Rf(x)dx=M$$

Then for all $S>M$, we have
$$\int_0^{R+2(S-M)/c} f(x)dx=M+\int_R^{R+2(S-M)/c} f(x)dx>M+\frac{c}{2}\frac{2(S-M)}{c}=S$$

Hence $\int_0^{\infty}f(x)dx$ diverges.

The proof is similar for $c<0$.

Hence we conclude that $c=0$.

Comment: How do we know that it doesn't diverge for $c=0$ as well?

Comment: It can diverge even if $c=0$. But given that it converges, $c$ must be $0$.

Comment: How do you see that?

Comment: Given $f(x)$ converges, I've proved that: If (statement p): $f(x)$ does not converge to $0$, then (statement Q): $\int_0^\infty f(x)dx$ diverges. So $P \implies Q$ and therefore $\neg Q \implies \neg P$, right? That means $\int_0^\infty f(x)dx$ converges $\implies$ $f(x) \to 0$. I hope I've made myself clear enough.

Comment: You said above that it can diverge even if $c=0$.

Comment: You are trying to prove that the integral converges implies $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)=0$, not $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$ implies the integral converges. Am I right?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: So I've proved it!

Comment: So $c=0$ because otherwise the integral couldn't be convergent at all?

Comment: @mavavilj Exactly!

Answer (score 0):

For all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ larger than 1,

Let 
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
0 \ for \ x\leq n
\\
n^4x-n^5 \ for \ n<x\leq n+1/n^3
\\
-n^4+2n+n^5 \ for \ n+1/n^3<x\leq n+2/n^3
\end{cases}$$
By some calculation
$\int_n^{n+1}f(x)dx=1/n^2$. Then $\int_0^\infty f(x) = \sum_{n=2}^\infty 1/n^2$

Comment: in addition if f is uniformly continous, then $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}f(x)=0$.